# Actual dates of when the sons of Yaakov died?

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes

The Yalkut Shimoni Shemot 162:9 lists the dates of births for the Tribes, and the age they died.

> ויהי כל נפש יוצאי ירך יעקב שבעים נפש ובעשו כתיב כל נפשות ביתו (כתוב ברמז קל"ח). ויוסף היה במצרים ראה עולם חדש (כתוב ברמז מ"ט). (סדר עולם) וימת יוסף וכל אחיו אין לך קצר ימים בשבטים פחות מיוסף ואין לך בשבטים שהאריך ימים יותר מלוי. שכל זמן שהיה לוי קיים לא נשתעבדו ישראל במצרים שנאמר וימת יוסף וכל אחיו וכל הדור ההוא ובני ישראל פרו. נמצא משמת לוי עד שיצאו ישראל ממצרים מאה ושש עשרה שנה אין שעבוד יותר עליו לא פחות משמונים ושש כשנותיה של מרים שנקראת על שם המרור. אמר ר' יהודה אמר רב שלשה דברים מקצרין ימיו של אדם (כתוב ברמז ס"ו). וימת יוסף וכל אחיו ראובן נולד בי"ד בכסליו מת בן מאה חמשים וחמש שנים. שמעון נולד בכ"ח בטבת ומת בן מאה ועשרים שנה. לוי נולד בי"ו בניסן ומת בן מאה שלושים ושבע שנים. יהודה נולד בט"ו בסיון ומת בן מאה ותשע עשרה שנים. דן בט' באלול ומת מאה ועשרים וחמש שנה. נפתלי נולד בה' בתשרי ומת בן מאה שלושים ושלוש שנה. גד בי' במרחשון ומת בן מאה ועשרים וחמש שנים. אשר בכ' בשבט ומת בן מאה ועשרים ושלש שנים. יששכר נולד בי' באב ומת בן מאה ועשרים ושתים שנים. זבולון בז' בתשרי ומת בן מאה ועשר שנה. בנימין נולד בי"א במרחשון ומת בן מאה וחמש עשרה שנים. באייר ושבט לא נולדו נשתייר לאפרים ומנשה:

This suggests their age of death would be as follows: 
Reuven 155, Shimon 120, Levi 137, Yehuda 119, Dan 125, Naftali 133, Gad 125, Asher 123, Yissachar 122, Zevulun 110, Binyamin 115

We know Yosef died at the age of 110 (see Vilna Gaon, Pninim MiShulchan HaGra Genesis 42:33) and that he was the first of the tribes to die (see Bereishit Rabbah 100:3).

Are there any sources that list the *actual date of death* for any of the tribes?

I know there are differing opinions as to the order of the birth of the tribes, such as the Yalkut above, Rashi, Ramban and Lekach Tov, but I am looking for a source for the date of death.

Comment: when you say "tribe" do you mean the "tribal father"?

Comment: You want a specific date, like 7 Iyar 2296? Or more generally, what year they died in? The latter is manageable; just take each of the opinions you cited and add these ages to them. But the former might be nigh-impossible to track down.

Comment: A few good places to look for this would be Seder HaDorot and the midrash, Sefer HaYashar.

Comment: The general understanding (as I've seen it) is that each tribe was _niftar_ on the same date he was born, per the dictum that Hashem "fills" the years of _tzadikim_. For the dates, you cited one list; the _Ya'avetz siddur_ has a similar list through the year, and indeed lists the dates as the _shevatim_ both being born and having died on the same day.

Comment: @ninamag yes the tribal father, meaning the sons of Yaakov

Comment: @DonielF Yes looking for a specific date

Comment: @Menachem thank you I will try to look into this.

Comment: Just to add a comment on the ages listed above, the Yalkut Shimoni appears to have an error on the age of Reuven as the piece before the one quoted says that Yosef was first to die and Levi was last to die. But if Reuven died at the age of 155 as above, he would have been the last to die. I checked in a Yalkut at the Zayit Ra'anan comments on this suggesting that in fact Reuven lived to 125 (not 155) and that would mean Levi was the last to die.